# Unable to create a WordPress.org account

Tags: wordpress.org

While I tried registering on wordpress.org, I did not receive any confirmation email from the website. 
When I tried again, it told me that:

> That email address already has an account.
> The registration is still pending, please check your email for the confirmation link.
> Resend confirmation email.

To double check, I checked the spam box as well. I've tried different emails again and again without success. I would appreciate any help you can provide. 
For details, see the image below:

[image]

Comment: We're not part of wordpress.org, sorry, we just know how to develop with their software. You'd have to ask them directly. However I'm struggling to see how you'd do that.

Comment: @Rup Therefore, how can I find somebody who knows the solution, considering that I can't access their forum since I cannot register

Comment: I guess you can't get into [WordPress Slack](https://wordpress.org/support/forum-user-guide/faq/#what-is-slack) either? I'd try the email address on this question - that sounds about right: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/update-my-wp-org-email-address/

Comment: @Abdoljabbar, if it's a problem with your mailbox, I'd suggest you use a service like https://temp-mail.org/ to generate a temporary email for the registration, so that you get the initial signup going. Later you should be able to your email from the profile page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent an email to **forum-password-resets@wordpress.org**, and they resolved the issue. They replied with the following reason:

**Why This Happened**

Due to the high volume of mail and signups we have at WordPress.org, and the sadly high number of fake accounts, we have a very complex system to try and catch bad actors before they make life miserable for everyone.

Sometimes that tool gets a little exuberant and false-flags. We are a actively working to improve this.